# Customize the background color of body for seperate pages

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular5

So i am using angular 5 and i am trying to customise the background color of the body of the home page but not to allow that color to be passed to the next page.

Using ng-deep i have kinda got this working as it works if the user refreshes the page. So how do i stop the body color white being passed into the next page and have grey show without having to refresh the page

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it from a component with:

```
 export class HomePageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   }
 }
```

Comment: It doesnt solve my problem as it still passes it onto the next page. that way every page now has a background of red. It seems to have a similar effect as ngdeep

Comment: You have to implement it in only in your home-page component, not in the AppComponent sorry, I edited my answer. So the color will only be apply in the home-page component.

Comment: i placed it in all my pages thankfully it wasnt that much so solved the problem of passing it. This way i can have what ever color i want for each page. Thanks alot buddy, solved a week long problem ive been ignoring

Comment: Good, just be careful that there are no conflicts (if you have multiple components in a page).